# Solution for WordData corruption

Tags: data

```mathematica
WordData["telecommuting", "BaseForm"]
```

return the result $Failed

but `Entity["Word","telecommuting"]["BaseForm"]` return like expect. That means WordData has an amount of data being corrupted.
I am trying to preload the data `WordData[All,"Preload"]. I don't know if it downloads data from the internet or not. "Preload" term is so unambiguous, but the results still the same corrupted.

The problem is, WordData, using, I guess, not sure if is it true or not, serialized local data, that is why it is very fast. Data from Entity framework is slow. Around 2s just to fetch any properties from one word.

I am not sure the amount of data is corrupted from WordData. But if it is big enough, it will affect the result. In workflow, `WordData["telecommuting", "BaseForm"]` return a `{$Failed}`, we have a solution that filter them. But if you add "List" as the third argument `WordData["telecommuting", "BaseForm","List]`. The internal of this function will trigger an Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   prop=WordData["telecommuting" , "Properties"]

{"AmericanSpelling", "Antonyms", "BaseAdjective", "BaseForm", 
 "BaseNoun", "BritishSpelling", "BroaderTerms", "CausesTerms", 
  "CompositeTerms", "ConceptWeight", "ConsequencesTerms", 
  "Definitions", "DerivedAdjectives", "DerivedAdverbs", 
  "EntailedTerms", "Examples", "GeographicDomain", "Hyphenation", 
  "InflectedForms", "MaterialTerms", "MorphologicalDerivatives", 
  "MorphologicalSource", "NarrowerTerms", "PartsOfSpeech", "PartTerms", 
  "PhoneticForm", "PorterStem", "SentenceFrames", "SimilarAdjectives", 
  "SimilarVerbs", "SubsetTerms", "SupersetTerms", "Synonyms", 
  "UsageField", "UsageType", "WholeTerms", "WordNetID"}

  Cases[ WordData[
       "telecommuting" , #] /. {{"telecommuting", "Noun"} -> #} & /@ 
           prop, Except[{_ -> {}}]]
```

Takes some time, "downloading indizes". Most entries are empty

```
 {"telecommuting", 
 {$Failed}, 
  "telecommuting", 
  {"BroaderTerms" -> {"employment",  "work"}}, 
  {"ConceptWeight" -> 0.5386585110529347}, 
  {"Definitions" -> "employment at home while communicating with the 
             workplace by phone or fax or modem"}, 
 Missing["NotAvailable"], 
 {"InflectedForms" -> {"telecommutings"}}, 
 {"Noun"}, 
 Style["tɛləkəmjˈutɪŋ", FontFamily -> "Arial Unicode MS"], 
  "telecommut", {"Synonyms" -> {"teleworking"}}, 
 {"WordNetID" -> "00585018"}}]
```

Comment: Yeah, your result is the same as mine, notice the second line, it returned {$Failed}, which is not normal, the document states that if data not exist yet, it will show Missing, `$Failed`  can only be because of some reason, data is corrupted. As I said, the same prop from the same word, but from Entity framework, will return available data.